# Finding nearest point outside series of geometries using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, point, geometry

I have a PostGIS database with a very large amount of geometries (circles), most of them overlapping. 
I'm trying to come up with a way to find the nearest point (from your current location) that is not within any of these circles.

Is this possible with a direct query?

So far I thought of a fishnet approach of 1x1 km cells that check for overlap with any of these circles. This works, but is not very accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using a PostGIS database, you could use the st_closestpoint function.
One argument would be your current location, the other one your inverted circle geometries.